# How to access list of dicts

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

Say you have a list of three dicts. The dicts have keys `name`: and `email`:. I know about doing a `list[0]`, which shows the keys and values of the first dict in the list. But how would I go about just displaying the name key and value of `list[0]`?

I've tried `list[0].name`, but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Have you tried `list[0]['name']`?

Comment: Ah thanks. Add this as answer and I'll credit you for it. I had tried that, but forgot about needing the quotes. Silly me.

Comment: I am trying to get used to the site, but I can't seem to understand why the question is downgraded. Can somebody help me understand. I want to improve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I've tried `list[0].name`, but that doesn't seem to work

This looks a bit like JavaScript to me. In Python, you have to use `list[0]['name']`.

Example:

```
>>> list = [{'name':'foo','value':23}, {'name':'bar','value':42}]
>>> list[0]['name']
'foo'
```